# linux running program to be shown again when console closed unfortunately

Tags: linux, command-line, installation, centos, putty

I am running a automatic installation in linux by running some command in cli

root@server$ sudo install some-devl

if unfortunatly even before the installation finishes the console become closed (putty to assume )

we can check if that is running or not by relaunching and running putty again with login

ps -eaf | grep install*

but is the anyway to continute to show in install output on screen again ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to make your session resilient to disconnections is to use [the screen command](http://www.rackaid.com/blog/linux-screen-tutorial-and-how-to/).

Another thing to try is to prevent the disconnects in the first place. One way is to set a [keep alive](http://rbgeek.wordpress.com/2013/03/16/keep-putty-ssh-sessions-from-disconnecting/).

Comment: Thanks .Say suppose because of OS issue putty has closed abruptly , if that is the what will be the soluton ?

Comment: Screen will allow you to go back to your old session.